# Use ExceptBy set operation with list of Keyselectors instead of single selector in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, list, entity-framework-core, except

I am working on a project where I have an Excel sheet with some data. I am converting it into list and mapping it into another list which is derived from table in a database using entity framework core.
I want to compare the two lists and store the records present in first list (database) but not in second list (Excel) into another list object. But the problem here is I don't have single field to relay on i.e. I don't have primary key so I created a candidate key with 4 fields (this number may change based on the list I send). I used `ExceptBy` but it works with one primary key as keyselector, I have to change it to accept multiple key selectors. And number of records in my list vary from 1,00,000 to 1,000,000. I don't know how to pass candidate key to `exceptby` function. This is what I tried.

```cs
public static IEnumerable<TSource> ExceptBy<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    IEnumerable<TSource> other,
    List<string> keyNames,
    IEqualityComparer<string> comparer = null)
{
    comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<string>.Default;

    var sets = keyNames.Select(keyName => new HashSet<string>(other.Select(item => 
    GetPropertyValue(item, keyName)), comparer)).ToList();

    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        var keys = keyNames.Select(keyName => GetPropertyValue(item, 
        keyName)).ToList();

        if (sets.All(set => set.Add(keys[sets.IndexOf(set)])))
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}

private static string GetPropertyValue<TSource>(TSource source, string propertyName)
{
    var property = typeof(TSource).GetProperty(propertyName);
    return property != null ? property.GetValue(source)?.ToString() : null;
}
```

And I use it like this

List primaryKeyName = new List();

```cs
var valuestobedeleted = mappedvalue.ExceptBy(users, primaryKeyName, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

I don't get proper output here. How to solve this. Is there any other way.

Thank you!!!

Comment: List of key fields is dynamic or you know about this in run-time? I this case we can creat generic function based on key. All keys are strings?

Comment: Yes,The List of key field is dynamic,its not on run time.Yes all keys are string.

Comment: Easiest way to concatenate strings and compare keys as one string. It is OK for you? I'm preparing solution and this is important question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple solution, which works using concatenation of key fields with `|` separator and `string.Format` method. Concatenation made using compiled function, which should be fast enough.

```cs
public static class CollectionUtils
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> ExceptBy<TSource>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource>  source,
        IEnumerable<TSource>       other,
        IEnumerable<string>        keyNames,
        IEqualityComparer<string>? comparer = null)
    {
        var keyExtractor = GenerateKeyFunction<TSource>(keyNames);

        var query = source
            .GroupJoin(other, s => keyExtractor(s), o => keyExtractor(o), (s, gj) => new { s, gj }, comparer)
            .Where(t => !t.gj.Any())
            .Select(t => t.s);

        return query;
    }

    static MethodInfo _formatMethodInfo =
        typeof(string).GetMethod(nameof(string.Format), new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(object[]) }) ??
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Format method not found");

    static Func<T, string> GenerateKeyFunction<T>(IEnumerable<string> propertyNames)
    {
        var entityParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");

        var args = propertyNames.Select(p => (Expression)Expression.PropertyOrField(entityParam, p))
            .ToList();

        var formatStr = string.Join("|", args.Select((_, idx) => $"{{{idx}}}"));

        var argsParam = Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(object), args);

        var body     = Expression.Call(_formatMethodInfo, Expression.Constant(formatStr), argsParam);
        var lambda   = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(body, entityParam);
        var compiled = lambda.Compile();

        return compiled;
    }
}
```